# Can Javascript calendar buttons be made independent of Local machine date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar

I have two calendar buttons in my web page based like start date and end date, and these buttons are used to filter records in my table.
Now, the filter will work only if my System(local machine) date format is mm-dd-yyyy but if I change my system date format  to like mm/dd/yyyy , the filter doesn't work.

Is it possible in any way that we can make the calendar buttons to function independent of the SYSTEM Local machine date format...

Comment: javascript is working client-side, you depend on client settings. If you're using a datepicker, you can probably specify the date format you expect it to output. If relying entirely on user typing the date, then you can only specify the expected format, maybe validate user input as much as possible, and then use the value assuming it's correct.

Comment: We can get the local system date in the javascript. Once you chabged the local system date use new Date() and apply or pass the same date to the Date picker.